# Access Windows localhost (virtual host) on iPad & Android Phone

Tags: wamp, virtualhost, vhosts

Can I access my local site on iPad & Android mobile. My site code is on wamp.

**httpd-vhosts.conf file Code**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.111:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www/mysite
    <Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/mysite/">
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts file code**

```
192.168.0.111       mysite.local
```

With the help of above code, I can access my site on iPad & Android phone through my Windows PC's LAN IP (ie 192.168.0.111)

http://192.168.0.111/index.php  **This is working fine.**

But I want to access my local site through its name. like:

http://mysite.local/index.php

Please help me.

Comment: You cannot, as the phone browser is going to attempt to find a domain name `mysite` by searching a DNS Server. And of course that will fail unless you have a local DNS Server correctly configured

Comment: Okay. Thank you @RiggsFolly